# What's the word or name for a person who can naturally & accurately estimate measurements such as size, capacity, ballance & angles?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

I'm sure I met someone like this a few years back & they provided me with a single word/name for the "condition".
I say condition as the person who this affects automatically, & sometimes to the point of frustrated distraction, will be able to see (can't ignore) the smallest discrepancy in any of these measurements within their environment & will also accurately estimate correction.
I'm not just talking about noticing a skewed wall mirror but rather an acute & often minute sense of balance in their surroundings.

Comment: The words to describe some of these attributes run from "obsessive-compulsive" to "detail-oriented" to "feng-shui-minded". Was it a single word, as you remember, or a compound word like my examples?

Comment: I don't know the word you're looking for.  Long time ago, when I was in the US Army, we sometimes joked about those able to consistently and accurately estimate the distance to the target as having a "calibrated eyeball".  Nowadays they just use laser rangefingers.

Comment: I don't think there's a *generic* term for "good at estimating". But in the specific case of estimating *capacity* (as, for example, *how many suitcases can you fit in your car boot?*), the word we usually use is ***woman***.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it was a single word which in itself didn't sound like a descriptor but more like a scientific term.

Comment: The word I'm looking for doesn't refer to how "good" a person is at the estimations rather how this persons eye is drawn to these things. Observations or discrepancies aren't generally/necessarily acted on but mental notes might be constant.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1015/

Comment: You mean **as·tute**? /əˈst(y)o͞ot/ *Adj* Having or showing an ability to accurately assess situations or people and turn this to one's advantage: "an astute businessman". (Google) **Syn**: *perspicacious*, *discerning*, *sharp*.

Answer (score 3):

A related word, although perhaps not the one you want, is *[savant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/savant#Noun)*, in the sense of a person exhibiting *savant syndrome*.  (Typically, such people have a disability that savant skills partly offset.)  The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savant_syndrome) on this topic mentions  spatial skills as among the  “five major areas” for savant skills.  It also says:

> No widely accepted cognitive theory explains savants' combination of talent and deficit. ... Another hypothesis is that savants hyper-systemize, thereby giving an impression of talent.  ... Also, the attention to detail shown by many savants is a consequence of enhanced perception or sensory hypersensitivity in these unique individuals.  It has also been confirmed that some savants operate by directly accessing low-level, less-processed information that exists in all human brains but is normally unavailable to conscious awareness.

On another tack (suggested by other answer) the term *[eagle-eyed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eagle-eyed)* describes someone who is perceptive and has excellent visual acuity.

Comment: You're right, Savant, that's certainly close in feel but not the word I'm looking for. Autistic characteristics had certainly occurred to me but I don't think autism was considered in the term I'm trying to find, the skill isn't so prodigious.

Answer (score 2):

There is a French expression, "*avoir le compas dans l'oeil*", for just what you describe. This would be roughly translated as "having your eye [accurate] as a compass" and means that you can just "see" what other people will have to measure.

Comment: I like that. It also echo's Cyberherbalists comment. There are probably many similar nods to this attribute.

Comment: And since your question was about English, let's bring this full circle. I vote for "compass-eye" or "to have a compass in one's eye." Even if it sounds painful. "Man, he sure does have a compass in his eye." "Thanks for sharing that highly relevant detail, compass-eye."

Comment: It sounds painful in French too.

Answer (score 0):

I would describe someone having the characteristics you listed as "spatially aware" or "spatially conscious."  "Situational awareness" is a closely related term used in the military to describe being attuned to your environment and its changes.

Answer (score 0):

[Obessive-Compulsive Disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder), and the related [Obsessive-Compulsive Personality Disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_personality_disorder), are psychological disorders whose sufferers often have extreme attention to detail *(along with anxiety over minute discrepencies in their environement)*.

Answer (score 0):

You could also be thinking of someone with [Photographic ("Eidetic") Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eidetic_memory).